# How do I impose a video with my face on a video with slides running on YouTube?

Tags: video-editor, editing

I would like to find out what the easiest way to take one video (of slides) as the main video and superimpose on it another video of a person speaking about those slides (in a small window at the upper right corner). These videos already exist (the two sync'ed videos), and I would like to upload them to YouTube. I am hoping there is an easy way to do that with a bunch of videos that doesn't require using too much editing (I know how to do it with iMovie, but it would take too much time to do it for all videos). Thanks.

Comment: You should check out https://obsproject.com/